# What is _proto_ and why is it always present faded away in any JS Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I open an object details in console.log, after the attached properties or functions I always see **"_ proto _"**. What is this and why is it always present even though I never declared anything like this in my object? I know it is related to some prototype feature but not exactly sure. Also, whereever it exists, whether plain js, jquery, or Angular.js it has the exact same 13 functions below it, viz. defineGetter, defineSetter, ...., set_proto.

Can someone explain it?

[image]

Comment: Everything you need read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: It's *the* prototype feature :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whenever you make any object in JavaScript it inherited from Object. so a object in java script have this structure

---

private members

*proto*-Reference of the prototype of current object parent.

prototype- Reference of the current objects prototype

---

So if you make any object let say named as object1

var object1=new Object();

it will be inherited from Object. and have *proto* set to Object(you can think Object as root class).